# Boto3 EMR - Hive step

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, boto, emr, boto3

Is it possible to carry out hive steps using boto 3? I have been doing so using AWS CLI, but from the docs (http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.add_job_flow_steps), it seems like only jars are accepted. If Hive steps are possible, where are the resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the previous version of Boto, there was a helper class named `HiveStep` which made it easy to construct the a job flow step for executing a Hive job. However in Boto3, the approach has changed and the classes are generated at run-time from the AWS REST API. As a result, no such helper class exists. Looking at the source code of `HiveStep`, https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/2d7796a625f9596cbadb7d00c0198e5ed84631ed/boto/emr/step.py it can be seen that this is a subclass of `Step`, which is a class with properties `jar` `args` and `mainclass`, very similar to the requirments in Boto3.

It turns out, all job flow steps on EMR, including Hive ones, still need to be instantiated from a JAR. Therefore you can execute Hive steps through Boto3, but there is no helper class to make it easy to construct the definition.

By looking at the approach used by `HiveStep` in the previous version of Boto, you could construct a valid job flow definition.

Or, you could fall back to using the previous version of Boto.

Comment: What would be an example of a hive step using Boto3? I can't seem to find any examples or pointers whatsoever. I would rather use the latest release label (4.0).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 4.0 release label?

Comment: It's the latest emr 4.0 release. It's passed as an argument from the CLI.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this to work using Boto3:

```
# First create your hive command line arguments
hive_args = "hive -v -f s3://user/hadoop/hive.hql"

# Split the hive args to a list
hive_args_list = hive_args.split()

# Initialize your Hive Step 
hiveEmrStep=[
        {
            'Name': 'Hive_EMR_Step',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': hive_args_list
            }
        },
    ]

# Create Boto3 session and client
session = boto3.Session(region_name=AWS_REGION,profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
client = session.client('emr')

# Submit and execute EMR Step
client.add_job_flow_steps(JobFlowId=cluster_id,Steps=hiveEmrStep)

#Where cluster_id is the ID of your cluster from AWS EMR (ex: j-2GS7xxxxxx)
```