# Airflow HiveCliHook connection to remote hive cluster?

Tags: hive, airflow

I am trying to connect to my hive server from a local copy of Airflow, but it seems like the HiveCliHook is trying to connect to my local copy of Hive.

I'm running to following to test it:

```
import airflow
from airflow.models import Connection
from airflow.hooks.hive_hooks import  HiveCliHook

usr = 'myusername'
pss = 'mypass'

session = airflow.settings.Session()
hive_cli = session.query(Connection).filter(Connection.conn_id == 'hive_cli_default').all()[0]

hive_cli.host = 'hive_server.test.mydomain.com'
hive_cli.port = '9083'
hive_cli.login = usr
hive_cli.password = pss
hive_cli.schema = 'default'

session.commit()

hive = HiveCliHook()

hive.run_cli("select 1")
```

Which is throwing this error:

```
[2018-11-28 13:23:22,667] {base_hook.py:83} INFO - Using connection to: hive_server.test.mydomain.com
[2018-11-28 13:24:50,891] {hive_hooks.py:220} INFO - hive -f /tmp/airflow_hiveop_2Fdl2I/tmpBFoGp7  
[2018-11-28 13:24:55,548] {hive_hooks.py:235} INFO - Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.3.4-bin/lib/hive-common-2.3.4.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true  
[2018-11-28 13:25:01,776] {hive_hooks.py:235} INFO - FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? My guess is that just [like every other `Airflow` `hook`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/sqoop_hook.py#L35) (and `operator`), this one also works only on **local `Hive` server** and it must be used in tandem with [`SSHHook`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py) in order to fire queries to *remote* Hive server.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because in the [docs](https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#scaling-out-with-celery) they clearly say `..For example, if you use the HiveOperator, the hive CLI needs to be installed on that box..` However looking at the [code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L81) I don't see any reason why it won't work for remote `Hive` servers

Answer (score 1):

- While you can use the `HiveCliOperator` (*unaltered*) for connecting and executing `HQL` statements in *remote* `Hive-Server`, the only requirement is that the **box that is running your `Airflow` `worker` must also contain `Hive` binaries installed**
- This is so because the [hive-cli command prepared by `HiveCliHook`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L100) would be run in *worker machine* via good-old `bash`. [At this stage](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L221), if `Hive CLI` is not installed in the machine where this code is running (i.e. your Airflow worker), it will break as in your case

---

Straight-forward workaround is to implement your own `RemoteHiveCliOperator` that

- Creates an [`SSHHook`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py) to the remote Hive-server machine
- And execute your HQL statement via SSHHook like [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py#L90)

---

In fact this seems to be a universal drawback with almost all Airflow `Operator`s that by default they expect requisite packages installed in every worker. The [docs](https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#scaling-out-with-celery) warn about it

> For example, if you use the HiveOperator, the hive CLI needs to be
>   installed on that box

Comment: Do note that a plausible risk associated with executing commands over `SSH` is **breaking of connection**. ([`SSHHook`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py#L145) uses [`paramiko`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/)) While its unlikely to bother you, if fault-tolerance is very high on your priority, you can [use `Emr-Steps` to execute `Hive` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410325/boto3-emr-hive-step)

Comment: Do note that `EMR-Steps` API has an inherent limitation of [sequential execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53156794/3679900)