# Triggering tasks on-premises hadoop cluster from cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to setup Google cloud platform Airflow managed service ( Cloud composer) in such a way that it should be able to trigger tasks in workflow at my on-premises Hadoop cluster instead on google cloud. I am unable to find much information about this. Cloud composer documentation tells about triggering jobs on shared VPC in Google cloud but not with the on-premises one. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092691/3679900) in case you want to perform `spark-submit` to remote `hadoop`-*cluster* via `Airflow`, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53743370/3679900) for hints on how to do pretty much anything on a remote machine (not necessarily `hadoop` cluster) through `SSH` / `Airflow`

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Composer runs its workers using CeleryExecutor pods within a GKE cluster. To trigger tasks in your on-premise infrastructure, you will need to configure the Composer environment such that the GKE cluster is reachable to/from your own network infrastructure, unless your infrastructure is accessible from the public internet.

To do this, consider investigating [Google Cloud Hybrid Connectivity](https://cloud.google.com/hybrid-connectivity/). You can use Cloud Interconnect and Cloud VPN to peer your on-premise infrastructure with a VPC, which you can configure Composer to use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Spark, you could make use of the [`SparkSubmitOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html?highlight=sparksubmitoperator#airflow.contrib.operators.spark_submit_operator.SparkSubmitOperator) in Airflow. The job (`jar` or `py` file) that will be submitted to Spark must connect to the IP address of your on-premise Hadoop cluster. Be aware that running this Spark job remotely will either require you to configure your firewall correctly (not recommended) or, indeed, run in a shared VPC. The latter creates a private network which contains both your cluster as well as your Airflow set-up, which allows both systems to securely communicate with each other.

Comment: By shared vpc do you mean I also need to setup a cloud vpn between gcp service(cloud composer) and my on-premises cluster?